# How to refresh a gallery after capturing a screenshot?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, screenshot, development-environment

I'm developing an application that takes screenshots by using a `BroadcastReceiver`. In the `onReceive` method, I take the screenshot and I save it in a `Screenshot/` directory. The problem is that I can see the screenshot in the folder but I can't see it in a gallery. Maybe because the gallery doesn't refresh? I've tried to use the `MediaScanner` class or the `sendBroadcast` method in my `BroadcastReceiver`, but it doesn't work because the application crashes.

How can I refresh the gallery after saving the images?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using for MediaScanner?  Also, when the application crashes, what do the logs say?

Comment: MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.toString() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() { public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) { Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":"); Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri); } });

Comment: When app crashes logs says: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.projet: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services

Comment: When I try to use sendBroadcast method I receive an error of permission denial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method.  It shouldn't have the permission issues.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, fileUri));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan. It works fine. I have forgotten to put the correct fileuri